# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in Transaction Model

Tags: php, laravel

I try get a CODE Transaction but i have error :

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' coalesce( MAX( CAST ( RIGHT( transaction_code, 5)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `coalesce( MAX( CAST ( RIGHT( transaction_code, 5)` as `UNSIGNED )) ,0 )` from `transactions` where `transaction_code` LIKE %TR% limit 1)

I have also tried php artisan migrate:fresh --seed and still get an error
and this my code for Transaction Model

```
class Transaction extends Model{
protected $table = 'transactions';
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function scopeGetCode($query)
{
    $string = "TR";
    //TR0001
    $selectLastCode = DB::raw(" coalesce( MAX( CAST ( RIGHT( transaction_code, 5) AS UNSIGNED )) ,0 ) as code ");
    $getData = $query->select("$selectLastCode")->where('transaction_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $string . '%')->first();


    $number = sprintf("%'.05d ", $getData->code + 1);

    return $string . $number;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->select(DB::raw("coalesce( MAX( CAST ( RIGHT( transaction_code, 5) AS UNSIGNED )) ,0 ) as code "))
```

The way you tried to use your `DB:raw` is like your column is named like your expression. Try the above solution.

Comment: i try this but , i still have error this : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coalesce(MAX(CAST (RIGHT(transaction_code, 5)AS UNSIGNED )) ,0 )' in 'field list' (SQL: select `coalesce(MAX(CAST (RIGHT(transaction_code, 5)AS UNSIGNED )) ,0 )` as `code ` from `transactions` where `transaction_code` LIKE %TR% limit 1)

Comment: Update my answer give it a try like that

Comment: @pr1nc3 I am not sure but I think should be in where clause something like this `->where(DB::raw("COALESCE(` as I said I am not sure.